# How to get respond value in jquery ajax and use for change p tags value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want use respond in if

```
var user =$("#username").val().toString();
    $.ajax({

        url: "/home/userex",
        method: "get",
        data: { username1 : user }

    }).done(function (res) {

        if (I want here use a respond respond is boolan) {
            $("#uservalidate").val('this user not valid');


    });
```

Comment: You can definitely do that.  How you are wanting to use it in the conditional is unclear.  What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The `res` data could be anything and we have no way to kow what type of data is being returned. Please review your Web Console > Network section to resulting headers. You may also want to include what you have tried so far as an `if` statement.

Comment: my respond has a boolean  i want chenge the tag value

Comment: @mohammadrahimi boolean can be represented in a number of ways, `true` or `false` and `1` and `0`. It's also possible that `"true"` or `"false"` is being returned. But if it is sending a Boolean variable back, you should be able to use `if(res){} else {}` type of statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're expecting a Boolean result, I would consider the following code:

```
$.get("/home/userex", {
  username1: $("#username").val()
}, function(res) {
  if (res) {
    $("#uservalidate").val('this user not valid');
  }
});
```

You may also consider using `$.getJSON()` is the results are in JSON. This is largely the same AJAX code you provided, just simplified a bit using `$.get()` instead of `$.ajax()`.